# Google AppEngine backend for Android not finding registered devices

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm following the tutorial https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

Everything seems to work fine, but the backend in the browser. Navigating to

```
localhost:8888
```

opens the backend UI but it can't find any registered devices. I can see 2 registered emulators in

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

The sample webapp is supposed to work out of the box, without making any changes? Am I right?

Comment: I've seen news today that Google Apps are having some kind of outage. That might be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me as well see a device is registered. But not from localhost: 8888 does not find any device.

There is no official forum google apps?